# issues with codingbat maxMirror exercise

Tags: java

So basically, I've been going through these codingBat problems, and when I get really stuck, I usually check out the solution and trace the logic and that has helped me not get stuck on later problems which used similar ideas.

This max mirror problem is not like the others for me personally; I have no idea how to actually write the code to solve it, even forming the algorithm is kind of tricky for me

> We'll say that a "mirror" section in an array is a group of contiguous elements such that somewhere in the array, the same group appears in reverse order. For example, the largest mirror section in `{1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1}` is length 3 (the `{1, 2, 3}` part). Return the size of the largest mirror section found in the given array.
>
> ```
> maxMirror({1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 3, 2, 1}) → 3
> maxMirror({1, 2, 1, 4}) → 3
> maxMirror({7, 1, 2, 9, 7, 2, 1}) → 2
> ```

Now, in terms of the algorithm, I sort of want to say something like, if we start by checking if the whole array is a mirror and then decrease the checked area size by 1 if it's not. But in terms of the pseudocode and the real code I have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My go to solution in cases like this where what your code should be doing is always doing it manually, then figuring out the essence of how it is that I am tackling the solution.

For this problem I found myself looking at possible subsets of the original array, then looking backwards through the original array to see if I can find that same subset again.

Next, I translated that into pseudocode,

```
for each segment in nums
   check if nums contains segment backwards
```

Repeated, but this time with more implementation details worked out.

```
for each segment in nums, starting with the largest
   reverse the segment
   check if nums contains reversed segment
   if it does, return the size of that segment
```

Next, find some likely candidates for methods in the pseudocode and write them. I chose to do this for "reverse" and "contains":

```
private int[] reverse(int[] nums) {
   int[] rtn = new int[nums.length];
   for (int pos = 0; pos < nums.length; pos++) {
      rtn[nums.length - pos - 1] = nums[pos];
   }
   return rtn;
}

private boolean contains(int[] nums, int[] segment) {
   for (int i = 0; i <= nums.length - segment.length; i++) {
      boolean matches = true;
      for (int j = 0; j < segment.length; j++) {
         if (nums[i + j] != segment[j]) {
            matches = false;
            break;
         }
      }
      if (matches) return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Finally, implement the rest:

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
   for (int window = nums.length; window > 0; window--) {
      for (int pos = 0; pos <= nums.length - window; pos++) {

         int[] segment = new int[window];
         for (int innerpos = 0; innerpos < window; innerpos++) {
            segment[innerpos] = nums[pos + innerpos];
         }

         segment = reverse(segment);
         if (contains(nums, segment)) {
            return window;
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My irrelevant two cents....

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums) {

  // maximum mirror length found so far
  int maxlen= 0;

  // iterate through all possible mirror start indexes
  for (int front = 0; front < nums.length; front++) {

    // iterate through all possible mirror end indexes
    for (int back = nums.length - 1; back >= front; back--) {

      // this inner for-loop determines the mirror length given a fixed
      // start and end index          

      int matchlen = 0;
      Boolean match = (nums[front] == nums[back]);

      // while there is a match
      //  1. increment matchlen
      //  2. keep on checking the proceeding indexes
      while (match) {

        matchlen++;

        int front_index = front + matchlen;
        int back_index = back - matchlen;

        // A match requires
        //  1. Thee indexes are in bounds
        //  2. The values in num at the specified indexes are equal
        match =
          (front_index < nums.length) &&
          (back_index >= 0) &&
          (nums[front_index] == nums[back_index]);
      }

      // Replace the max mirror length with the new max if needed
      if (matchlen > maxlen) maxlen = matchlen;
    }
  }

  return maxlen;
}
```

Alternative solution designed to confuse you

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
  return maxlen_all_f(nums, 0);
}

int maxlen_all_f(int [] nums, int f) {
  return (f >= nums.length)
    ? 0
    : max(
        maxlen_for_start_f(nums, f, nums.length - 1),
        maxlen_all_f(nums, f + 1)
      );
}

int max(int a, int b){
  return (a > b)
    ? a
    : b;
}

int  maxlen_for_start_f(int [] nums, int f, int b) {
 return (b < f)
   ? 0
   : max(
       matchlen_f(nums, f, b),
       maxlen_for_start_f(nums, f, b - 1)
     );
}

int matchlen_f(int[] nums, int f, int b) {
  return match_f(nums, f, b)
    ? 1 + matchlen_f(nums, f + 1, b - 1)
    : 0;
}

Boolean match_f(int [] nums, int a, int b) {
  return (a < nums.length && b >= 0) && (nums[a] == nums[b]);
}
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and readers need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple rather than making it complex:

```
public static int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
    final int len=nums.length;
    int max=0;
    if(len==0)
        return max;
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    { 
        int counter=0;
        for(int j=(len-1);j>i;j--)
        {
            if(nums[i+counter]!=nums[j])
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }

        max=Math.max(max, counter);
    }

    if(max==1)
        max=0;      
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the best solution in terms of performance. Any further improvements are invited.

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
 int maxMirror=0;

 for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++)
 {
   int mirror=0;
   int index=lastIndexOf(nums,nums[i]);
   if(index!=-1){
    mirror++;

    for(int j=i+1;j<nums.length;j++)
    {
       if(index>=0&&existsInReverse(nums,index,nums[j]))
       {      
         mirror++;
         index--;
         continue;

        }
        else 
         break; 
    }

    if(mirror>maxMirror)
     maxMirror=mirror;
   }
 }

 return maxMirror; 
}


int lastIndexOf(int[] nums,int num){
 for(int i=nums.length-1;i>=0;i--)
 {
   if(nums[i]==num)
    return i;
 }
 return -1;
}

boolean existsInReverse(int nums[],int startIndex,int num){
  if(startIndex!=0&&(nums[startIndex-1]==num))
   return true;
  return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer , Hope the comments explain it well :)

```
public int maxMirror(int[] nums) {
  int max = 0;
  // our largest mirror section found stored in max

  //iterating array 
  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    int iterator = i; // iterator pointing at one element of array
    int counter = 0;//counter to count the mirror elements

    //Looping through for the iterator element
    for(int j=nums.length-1;j>=i;j--){

      //found match i.e mirror element
      if(nums[iterator] == nums[j]){
        iterator++; // match them until the match ends
        counter++; // counting the matched ones
      }
       else{
            //matching ended
                  if(counter >= max){//checking if previous count was lower than we got now
                      max = counter; // store the count of matched elements
                  }
                  counter = 0; // reset the counter
                  iterator = i; // reset the iterator for matching again
              }
    }
    if(counter >= max){//checking if previous count was lower than we got now
      max = counter;// store the count of matched elements at end of iteration
    }

  }

  return max;//return count
}
```